# I have a question about Google Purchase Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-billing

I am using billingclient:billing:4.0.0. When a subscription or a product is sold, I want to register it. So for example,

```
sub_1
sub_2
sub_3
```

Let's say I have a product, when my user buys `sub_2`, I want to record his purchase by sending him a warning message. What step should I use to do this? In other words, after determining that the purchase has been fully approved and passed all security, I will record this information in my database. I am not sure at which step I should make this recording.
Many sources say I should do this under onPurchasesUpdated, but I can't be sure. Which is the most correct usage?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Answer (score 0):

**You can track using billingClient object acknowledgePurchase Listener as below:**

```
 billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams) { itBillingResult ->

}
```